# In Ender's Game, how do the kids control the ships?

Tags: enders-game

In the final battles, how do the kids like Bean, Petra, Dink, etc. control the fleet's ships?

Comment: You *do* remember what ansible is? So what exactly about controlling the fleet you want to know?

Comment: you could like read the actual book

Answer (score 6):

This is addressed in the [source novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game). The various fighters are manned by actual pilots following verbal instructions given to them by their commander/s. Ender (and presumably by extension his squadron leaders; Bean, Petra, Dink, etc) can assume *direct* control of single ships, but only by ignoring all of their other ships and leaving them to their own devices.

> **He spoke commands to simulated pilots of four fighters, and instead of merely carrying out the computer's instructions, he was allowed to determine tactics himself, deciding which of several objectives was the most valuable** and directing his squadron accordingly. **At any time he could take personal command of one of the fighters for a short time,** and at first he did this often; when he did, however, the other three fighters in his squadron were soon destroyed, and as the games became harder and harder he had to spend more and more of his time commanding the squadron.

Commands are relayed via an FTL communication technology known as the ansible. This allows command to be conducted from within Earth's system while various fleets approach the planets controlled by the Buggers.

> "We knew then that it was possible to communicate faster than light.
> That was seventy years ago, and once we knew it could be done, we did
> it. Not me, mind you, I wasn't born then." "How is it possible?" "I
> can't explain philotic physics to you. Half of it nobody understands
> anyway. What matters is we built the ansible. The official name is
> Philotic Parallax Instantaneous Communicator, but somebody dredged the
> name ansible out of an old book somewhere and it caught on. Not that
> most people even know the machine exists." "That means that ships
> could talk to each other even when they're across the solar system,"
> said Ender. "It means," said Graff, "that ships could talk to each
> other even when they're across the galaxy.